# Deleting an array of linked list in c++

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I created buckets to insert my data and everything works fine except for the deletion of all nodes. If I delete my container using `delete[] container` then only the first nodes of all my linked lists will be deleted. I think what I did was logical but it does not work. Could you tell me why?(Only the last loop of the function is of concern other bits of code are for reference.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

struct bucket{
    int val;
    bucket* next;
};


int countDigit(int max){
    int digits = 0;
    while(max>0){
        max = max/10;
        digits++;
    }
    return digits;
}

int findMax(int* arr, int l, int r){
    int max = arr[l];
    for(int i = l+1; i<=r; i++){
        if(max<arr[i]){
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

void createBucket(int* arr, int l, int r){
    int max = findMax(arr, l, r);
    int digits = findDigit(max);
    int divide = pow(10, digits-1);
    int maxPos = max/divide;
    int pos;//position of elements in the container
    bucket* container = new bucket[maxPos+1];
    bucket* cursor;
    //copying elements to their respective buckets
    for(int i=l; i<=r; i++){

        pos = arr[i]/divide;

        if(container[pos].val == 0){
            container[pos].val = arr[i];
            container[pos].next = NULL;
        }
        else{
            bucket* node = new bucket;
            cursor = &container[pos];
            node->val = arr[i];
            while(cursor->next!=NULL){
                cursor = cursor->next;
            }
            cursor->next = node;
            node->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    //copying the elements from the buckets to their respective position
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<maxPos+1; i++){
        cursor = &container[i]; 
        while(cursor!=NULL && cursor->val!=0){
            arr[j] = cursor->val;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            j++;
        }
    }
    //deleting all nodes
    bucket* tmp;
    for(int i= 0; i<maxPos+1; i++){
        cursor = &container[i];
        while(cursor!=NULL){
            tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

It gives out error as follows:

```
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Custom types should start with a capital letter. Name your parameters better. `nullptr` over `NULL`. Having to explicitly set stuff to 'null' after construction means your constructor needs work. Finally, if `delete [] container;` isn't working, it means your bucket destructor is broken.

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: It might help to see your bucket class. Because I'm a little confused about how your code even compiles.

Comment: Your code deletes `&container[i]` which was never allocated with `new` in the first place. `delete[] container;` looks right to me, not sure I understand your problem with it. But seeing more code might help.

Comment: You don't have a linked list class. You're just trying to string nodes together. There is a big difference, and it explains why you're having memory issues. `findDigit` is a bad name. Your not finding anything, you're counting digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue is that you don't actually have a linked list. You have a node struct, and you are attempting to string nodes together, but you are lacking an actual class to maintain your data structure for you.

Naturally, when you try to delete the array, only the first node of each index is deleted. You have zero code to handle deleting the whole list.

Below is a short sample of a linked list class. It's missing quite a bit of functionality, but it has enough to demonstrate some good practices and how it works.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class IntList {
 public:
  IntList() = default;
  ~IntList();                           // Rule of 5
  IntList(const IntList& other);        // Rule of 5
  IntList(IntList&& other) noexcept;    // Rule of 5
  IntList& operator=(IntList other);    // Rule of 5
  IntList& operator=(IntList&& other);  // Rule of 5
  void push_back(int value);
  void print() const;  // Only here for ease of demo

  friend void swap(IntList& lhs, IntList& rhs);

 private:
  struct Node {
    int m_key = 0;
    Node* m_next = nullptr;

    Node(int key) : m_key(key) {}
  };

  Node* m_head = nullptr;
  Node* m_tail = nullptr;
};

IntList::~IntList() {
  while (m_head) {
    Node* tmp = m_head;
    m_head = m_head->m_next;
    delete tmp;
  }

  m_head = nullptr;
  m_tail = nullptr;
}

IntList::IntList(const IntList& other) {
  if (other.m_head) {
    // Set up first node
    this->m_head = new Node(other.m_head->m_key);
    m_tail = m_head;
    Node* otherWalker = other.m_head->m_next;
    while (otherWalker) {  // Handles the rest of the nodes
      m_tail->m_next = new Node(otherWalker->m_key);
      m_tail = m_tail->m_next;
      otherWalker = otherWalker->m_next;
    }
  }
}

IntList::IntList(IntList&& other) noexcept : IntList() { swap(*this, other); }

IntList& IntList::operator=(IntList other) {
  swap(*this, other);

  return *this;
}

IntList& IntList::operator=(IntList&& other) {
  swap(*this, other);

  return *this;
}

void IntList::push_back(int value) {
  Node* tmp = new Node(value);
  if (!m_head) {
    m_head = tmp;
    m_tail = m_head;
    return;
  }

  m_tail->m_next = tmp;
  m_tail = tmp;

  return;
}

void IntList::print() const {
  Node* walker = m_head;

  if (!walker) {
    std::cout << "Empty List.\n";
  }

  while (walker) {
    std::cout << walker->m_key << (walker->m_next ? ' ' : '\n');
    walker = walker->m_next;
  }
}

void swap(IntList& lhs, IntList& rhs) {
  using std::swap;

  swap(lhs.m_head, rhs.m_head);
  swap(lhs.m_tail, lhs.m_tail);
}

int main() {
  IntList one;
  one.push_back(42);
  one.push_back(55);

  IntList two(one);

  IntList three;
  three.push_back(350);
  three.push_back(240);
  three.push_back(609);

  IntList four(three);
  four.push_back(666);


  // While I can appreciate learning, there's no reason for a dynamically 
  // allocated array. SO trope of use a vector instead applies here. NOTE: a 
  // vector would not have helped with your code, it just takes away your 
  // responsibility to delete the array later. You'd still leak memory.
  IntList* const container = new IntList[4];
  container[0] = one;
  container[1] = two;
  container[2] = three;
  container[3] = four;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    container[i].print();
  }

  delete[] container;
}
```

`IntList` is a class that represents a singly linked list of integers. The data members `m_head` and `m_tail` represent the beginning and end of the list, respectively. `m_tail` is optional, but I find it makes life easier if you know where the list ends. Doubly linked lists also make your life a LOT easier when it comes to erasing from the middle and they're not that much harder to write.

The list is made up of nodes, where a node points to the location of the next node. You've got this already.

The key function that solves your problem is the destructor, `~IntList()`. Examine that function closely. Notice how it moves through your whole list, deleting every node as it goes. *This is what you're missing.* That, and the actual list class to do all of this.

Because each `IntList` object takes care of its own memory, I only need to delete the dynamic array. As the array destroys itself, it will call the destructor of each element. This means that after every `IntList` element has cleaned up after itself, the array memory is then deleted. No leaks, and no double frees.

The biggest thing that helps in understanding data structures is drawing it out.

The good practices that I mentioned are the Rule of 5 functions (Rule of 0/3/5) and the copy-swap idiom. The Rule of 5 is necessary since the linked list class is managing dynamic resources. The main function is taking full advantage of the copy constructor. Note that the array contains copies of the lists. If I didn't want copies, I would have to declare the array as a double pointer and allocate an array of pointers to `IntLists`. The `IntList`s would then clean themselves up at the end of the main function.

The copy-swap idiom just makes life easier and reduces code duplication.